# Reverse `...` method Ruby

Tags: ruby

Is there a standard method in ruby similar to `(1...4).to_a` is `[1,2,3,4]` except reverse i.e. `(4...1).to_a` would be `[4,3,2,1]`?

I realize this can easily be defined via `(1...4).to_a.reverse` but it strikes me as odd that it is not already and **1)** am I missing something? **2)** if not, is there a functional/practical reason it is not already?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest is probably this:

```
4.downto(1).to_a #=> [4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Alternatively you can use `step`:

```
4.step(1,-1).to_a #=> [4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Finally a rather obscure solution for fun:

```
(-4..-1).map(&:abs) #=> [4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 8):

`(1...4)` is a Range.  Ranges in ruby are not like arrays; one if their advantages is you can create a range like

```
(1..1e9)
```

without taking up all of your machine's memory.  Also, you can create this range:

```
r = (1.0...4.0)
```

Which means "the set of all floating point numbers from 1.0 to 4.0, including 1.0 but not 4.0"

In other words:

```
irb(main):013:0> r.include? 3.9999
=> true
irb(main):014:0> r.include? 3.99999999999
=> true
irb(main):015:0> r.include? 4.0
=> false
```

you can turn an integer Range into an array:

```
irb(main):022:0> (1..4).to_a
=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

but not a floating point range:

```
irb(main):023:0> (1.0...4.0).to_a
TypeError: can't iterate from Float
        from (irb):23:in `each'
        from (irb):23:in `to_a'
        from (irb):23
        from /home/mslade/rubygems1.9/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

Because there is no natural way to iterate over floating point numbers.  Instead you use `#step`:

```
irb(main):015:0> (1..4).step(0.5).to_a
=> [1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0]
irb(main):016:0> (1...4).step(0.5).to_a
=> [1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 3.5]
```

If you need to iterate backwards through a large integer range, use [`Integer#downto`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Integer.html#method-i-downto).

Comment: What about `('1.0'...'4.0').to_a.map(&:to_f)`?

Comment: That's a neat trick but it only works for 10^N.  What if you wnat it in steps of, say, 0.05?

Comment: `('0.00'..'10.00').step(5).to_a.map(&:to_f)` or leave `to_a.map` and get enumerator with strings.

Answer (score 1):

You could patch Range#to_a to automatically work with reverse like this:

```
class Range

  alias :to_a_original :to_a

  def reverse
    Range.new(last, first)
  end

  def to_a
    (first < last) ? to_a_original : reverse.to_a_original.reverse
  end

end
```

Result:

```
(4..1).to_a
=> [4, 3, 2, 1]
```

This approach is called "re-opening" the class a.k.a. "monkey-patching". Some developers like this approach because it's adding helpful functionality, some dislike it because it's messing with Ruby core.)